# Browsers do not open website. show there is no internet connection

Tags: google-chrome, nginx

I open a website in windows 7 "example.com". Chrome redirect me to https://example.com/. It  works fine, When i click on a link in the website then chrome redirect to me at "example.com/product/xyz/" and show error "Your connection to this site is not secure" and remove https from the link. Most of the links are also not opened show same error. eg-('google.co.in', 'www.pixabey.com' etc.).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That means that the website your are visiting doesn't provide HTTPS and the browser is just notifying you that. That should not affect you browsing, it is just a warning .

Comment: But the same link works perfectly in another device and mobile also.